# Enabling remote file access on windows server 2008

Tags: windows, file-permissions, remote-access

I have an application (c# wcf) running on `serverA` (windows server 2012) trying to create a folder on `serverB` (windows server 2008) with path `\\serverB.example.org\d$\test\newFolder`. The user has full control on the folder `\\serverB.example.org\d$\test\` but gets permission denied even when just trying to read. If i add the user to the `Administrators` group then the folder is created without issue (i don't want to have to give admin rights to my application). The permissions on the folder `\\serverB.example.org\d$\test\` are:

```
serverB\Administrators - Full Control
myDomain\testUser - Full Control
```

`myDomain\testUser` is the user running the application. Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this permission issue.

Edit:

I have tried putting `Everyone` `Full Control` and this does not prevent the permission denied either.

I have tried running the application locally on serverB and it works - only have permission issues on remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the ntfs permissions were correct I had to also give the permissions on the share. After that no more permissions denied.